# appendChild (same const) multiple times?

Tags: javascript

When I run this, I'd expect 4 `<li class="event-wrap">` elements to get created and appended in eventsNode, but only one does.

What's the correct way to create an element and add it as many times as you want?

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.classList = 'event-wrap';
eventsNode.appendChild(li);
eventsNode.appendChild(li);
eventsNode.appendChild(li);
eventsNode.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: You have literally created an element `singular` not elements therefore when you append the element you created 4 times it's basically like refreshing itself, you should either clone it or create `x` new elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone `li` first

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.classList = 'event-wrap';
eventsNode.appendChild(li.cloneNode());
eventsNode.appendChild(li.cloneNode());
eventsNode.appendChild(li.cloneNode());
eventsNode.appendChild(li.cloneNode());
```

Comment: I suppose I could throw it in a loop if I need a thousand?

Comment: In that case I'd suggest creating a function that returns a new <li> element as suggested by @ErlisarVasquez. The reason your code doesn't work is because you can't keep adding an element that already is in the DOM. My suggestion was merely intended to demonstrate that point. I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing that.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. I just didn't realize that created elements exist as a unique entities in the dom, even without IDs. I thought if was assigned to a variable / const that it could be re-used. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** You can't append one object multiple times. Just simply clone it. Then feed it in a for-loop.

```js
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.classList = 'event-wrap';
for (var i=0; i<4 ; i++){
  eventsNode.appendChild(li.cloneNode());
}
```

**Method 2:**
If you want to manually create objects you can also do this:

```js
const li1 = document.createElement('li');
const li2 = document.createElement('li');
const li3 = document.createElement('li');
const li4 = document.createElement('li');
li1.classList = 'event-wrap';
li2.classList = 'event-wrap';
li3.classList = 'event-wrap';
li4.classList = 'event-wrap';
eventsNode.appendChild(li2);
eventsNode.appendChild(li3);
eventsNode.appendChild(li4);
eventsNode.appendChild(li5);
```

Of course you can create your own function that returns the said objects.